# What does the begining of his path mean?

Tags: proverbs

Proverbs 8:22-24

> The Lord acquired me [Wisdom/Chokmah/Sophia] at the beginning of his path, the first of his acts of long ago. Ages ago I was set up, at the first, before the beginning of the earth. When there were no depths I was brought forth, when there were no springs abounding with water.

Also, what does the First of his acts of long ago mean?

Answer (score 2):

His-Way = דַּרְכּ֑וֹ "Dark-o" in [Mishlei | "Proverbs" 8:22] : "YHVH acquired me at the beginning of His way, before His works of old." (יְֽהוָ֗ה קָ֖נָנִי רֵאשִׁ֣ית דַּרְכּ֑וֹ קֶ֖דֶם מִפְעָלָ֣יו מֵאָֽז)

Based on Bereshit 1:3-4 (**before His works of old**), Elohim generates א֑וֹר Or = "Light" to distinguish good things in the universe & in the process utters 6-letters of the alef-beyt : " יְהִי א֑וֹר " (Yehi Or).

Elohim uses The-Light to see Good, separating His-Way from darkness in the universe. (וַיַּ֧רְא אֱלֹהִ֛ים אֶת־הָא֖וֹר כִּי־ט֑וֹב וַיַּבְדֵּ֣ל אֱלֹהִ֔ים בֵּ֥ין הָא֖וֹר וּבֵ֥ין הַחֽשֶׁךְ)

"Wisdom" חָ֖כְמָה (Chokmah) in Proverbs 8 is "The-Light" הָא֖וֹר (Ha-Or) of Genesis 1. | "Light" **Or** Wisdom reveals Elohim's choice to see טֽוֹב Good in הָאָ֗רֶץ the-earth.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the broader context, NIV Proverbs 8:

> 22“The Lord brought me forth as the first of his works,
> before his deeds of old;
> 23 I was formed long ages ago,
> at the very **beginning**, when the **world** came to be.

It is talking about the beginning of the world.

> 24 When there were no watery depths, I was given birth,
> when there were no springs overflowing with water;
> 25before the mountains were settled in place,
> before the hills, I was given birth,
> 26 **before he made the world** or its fields
> or any of the dust of the earth.

More precisely, before God made the world, wisdom existed.

> 27 I was there when he set the heavens in place,

In fact, even before God fixed the heavens.

> when he marked out the horizon on the face of the deep,
> 28 when he established the clouds above
> and fixed securely the fountains of the deep,
> 29when he gave the sea its boundary
> so the waters would not overstep his command,
> and when he marked out the foundations of the earth.
> 30 Then I was constantly at his side.

Wisdom was with God.

> I was filled with delight day after day,
> rejoicing always in his presence,
> 31rejoicing in his whole world
> and delighting in mankind.

What does the begining of his path mean?

the beginning of creation.

What does the First of his acts of long ago mean?

Wisdom existed before time was created.